# Create Spreadsheet in Excel of Name and File Type Using Script

Tags: excel, batch-file, cmd

I have a bunch of excel files and other types of files that I need to populate into a spreadsheet to keep track of them. I was what the batch script would look like for such task. Also I want to be able to pin point which folders I want to get the file names from.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You would write a script in VBA using the `Dir` command.

Comment: @jbarker, or even `dir /b > filelist.csv` as a simple dos command

Comment: True, but that doen't meet his requirement for being able to specifiy multiple file locations into a single file.

Comment: @jbarker2160 Never dealt with VBA scripts how exactly would I do this. Also how would the code look?

Comment: @duckfeet23, SO is not a code-upon-request site.  If you have some code you'd like for us to debug we'd be more than happy.  Tyr Googling "Get File List Excel." Depending on how detailed your requirements are this could be a pretty large script.

Comment: @jbarker2160 Chillout BRAH no disrespect here. I respect you brah. I figured it out and thanks for yah help brah no disrespect!

Answer (score 0):

Dir does do multiple folders.

```
dir c:\windows "c:\program files\e*.txt" /a
```

Here's doing My Docs.

```
for /f "skip=2 tokens=3" %A in ('Reg query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v "Personal"') do set doc=%A

for /f "usebackq tokens=2* delims= " %i IN (`dir "%doc%" /a /s ^|findstr /i /v "\/"^|findstr /l /v "Pictures Music Video"`) DO @echo %j&echo.
```